# Prove the following by induction the following expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

[image: Prove by induction the following]

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this problem
I get stuck after introducing the induction hypothesis on $p(n+1)$

$p(n)=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+n)=2^n\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\dots(2n-1)$

$p(n+1)= (n+1+1)(n+2+1)(n+3+1)\dots(n+n)\cdot(n+n+1)=2^{n+1}\dots1\cdot3\cdot5\dots(2n+1)$

$(n+1+1)(n+2+1)(n+3+1)2^n\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2n-1)(n+n+1)=2^{n+1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2n+1)$

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By the way, on the left hand side, the last term is $(n+1+n+1)$ not $(n+n+1)$

Answer (score 2):

$p(n+1)=(n+1+1)(n+1+2)\cdots (n+1+n+1)=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}p(n)=2(2n+1)p(n)$

as required.

Comment: How did you get  n+1 below (2n+1)(2n-1)?

Comment: $(n+2)\cdots(2n)=\frac{1}{n+1}(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (2n)=\frac{1}{n+1}p(n)$.  Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

No need for induction here. If you multiply the LHS by $n!$, you get $(2n)!$. And if you multiply the RHS by $n!$, then you get\begin{align}n!\times2^n\times1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)&=(1\times2)\times(2\times2)\times\cdots\times(n\times2)\\&\phantom=\ \ \times1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)\\&=2\times4\times\cdots\times(2n)\times1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)\\&=(2n)!\end{align}

Comment: I would like to know why multiplying by n! proves the equality as for today (first year engineering student) I'm learning to use the induction method

Comment: I did not use induction. And if you want to prove that a number $a$ is equal to a number $b$, then this is the same thing as proving that $n!\times a$ is equal to $n!\times b$.